# CSS sticky footer with margin-top on main wrapper

Tags: html, css

I've been using http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ and it works great until you need a margin/padding at the top of the page. The design I'm working with has a patterned body and all the page content is in a white box that starts 15px from the top. I still need a footer that sticks to the bottom cross browser. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for all the ideas but noting works perfectly. Adding a margin to a sub element of the wrapper puts in an *un-nessary scrollbar*: Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/cronoklee/p2cPD/

Comment: tell the creative department to suck it, its staying at the top?

Comment: Is it possible to wrap your content in a div and apply a top padding to your wrapper div instead of adding it to the body? ...Er, inside his .wrapper class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're open to scrapping the sticky footer you've been using, here's how I would go about making one from scratch.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        ... Your Content Here ...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    ... Your Footer Here ...
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    background: #eee;
    padding: 15px 0 100px;
}

.content {
    background: #fff;
}

.footer {
    background: #ccc;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
}
```

That should work cross browser. The only nuance about this to be aware of is that `position: fixed` doesn't work in IE 6. Any improvements are welcome :)

Comment: Thanks - Really close Tracy! The only problem now is that with the absolute positioning the content-wrapper does not expand when its content is too long for the page height. I'm not sure we're gonna solve this...

Answer (score 0):

Could you apply a margin-top to the body?

```
body{
margin-top:15px;
}
```

This works with firebug on the page you linked to.

Comment: It adds a scrollbar actually. Sticky footers are really supposed to avoid this

Answer (score 0):

A solution without adding a scrollbar. Make these adjustments:

```
.header{
height:168px; /*15px + image height*/
image-position:bottom;
margin-bottom:37px;
}

.download{
top:175px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just found this thread since I have had the same problem ten minutes ago and I'd like to share my solution to the problem with "*unnecessary scrollbar caused by vertically-down-shifted footer caused by my header-div with margin-top: 20px, because I just want it to be 20px from the very top of the page*", which I came up in the meantime.

Just **change your `.content{margin-top:15px;}` to `.content{padding-top:15px;}`** and it should work. The scrollbar should disappear and the content has it's distance from the top.

As seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/p2cPD/24/

Yes - it will expand the content-div's background, but if you don't want it there it can be solved by using some transparent png of some sort or whatever.

Also, according to the http://ryanfait.com the `<div class="push"></div>` thing should be at the end inside wrapper-div and after content-div, not inside content-div.

Comment: Yes a padding works but the whole point was to have the white box appear to start 15px from the top. How can this be solved with "some transparent png of some sort or whatever" ?

Comment: Well, the content of the white box _starts_ 15px from the top. The illusion of the whole box (content **AND the background**) starting 15px from the top could be done with "some transparent png of some sort or whatever" with 'background' properly set.
Something like http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/5623/htmlcssproblem.jpg